# How Manage Client Computer Backup in Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, server, client, backup

I am looking for information on how to make client computer backup in Windows Server 2019. All the information I've found so far concerns making backup copies for local Windows Server. I have two computers at home that my family uses and I would like the system settings, files and programs to be periodically copied to the server so that in the event of a system failure I could easily restore working settings.

Does Windows Server 2019 have built-in tools for this purpose, or do I have to look for a solution in third-party applications?

Thank you.

Online tutorials and built-in options in Windows Server 2019.